# AWS AppSync add multiple children into one parent attribute with existence check resolver

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync, vtl

I have a question of AWS AppSync. I wonder whether there is a way to check existence while adding multiple values into one attribute of the parent.

So, here is my example:

This is User type:
[User type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I6Ia.png)

Here is what the dynamodb looks like:
[dynamodb item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prhN7.png)

And here is what I want t accomplish: To add three programs into a user record, under the programs attribute.
[the addProgramToUser mutation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWXUC.png)

And here is my current resolver:
[the addProgramToUser resolver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfNLe.png)

So I my logic is to extract the existent programs from dynamodb first, and then check whether the "To Be Added" program Ids are in there. If there is, stop the updating or skip that program id. If there is not, continue the update. So the question is, how to extract current data using the VTL and how to compare the existent ones and the ones I want add.

Or if anyone has other idea of how I can accomplish this task, please help. Thanks so much. I cannot embed the pictures since I am new on stackoverflow. So sorry for the inconvenience. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can use a condition for your resolver's request mapping template. A condition expression lets you tell AWS AppSync and DynamoDB whether the request should succeed or not based on the state of the object already in DynamoDB before the operation is performed. For example, in your case, you only want the UpdateItem request to succeed if there is no program id in Dynamo already.

```
{
   "version" : "2017-02-28",
   "operation" : "PutItem",
   "key" : {
      "id" : { "S" : "1" }
   },
   "condition" : {
      "expression" : "attribute_not_exists(programId)"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Lonut. Sorry for the delay. I did try the "attribute_not_exists(programId)", but it did not work. For my situation, I am adding multiple programIds. I dont know whether this condition expression will still work.